# Isomorphism of hyperreal fields viewed as extensions of the real field

Tags: logic, field-theory, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis, ordered-fields

Crossposted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/368381/461

Let $A$ be the $\mathbb R$-algebra of all $\mathbb R$-valued functions on $\mathbb N$, that is
$$
A=\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}=\prod_{n\in \mathbb N}\mathbb R.
$$
Let $\mathfrak a$ be the ideal of $A$ formed by the finitely supported $\mathbb R$-valued functions on $\mathbb N$, that is
$$
\mathfrak a=\mathbb R^{(\mathbb N)}=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb R.
$$
Let $M$ be the set of those maximal ideals of $A$ which contain $\mathfrak a$.

Let us assume the Continuum Hypothesis.

I will make four statements, and my question will be: are these statements true? (I think they *are* true, but I'm far from being sure.)

(1) The fields $A/\mathfrak m$ and $A/\mathfrak n$ are isomorphic for all $\mathfrak m,\mathfrak n\in M$.

(2) Statement (1) follows from Corollary 6.1.2 in the book **Model Theory** (1990) by Keisler, H. Jerome and Chen-Chung Chang.

Here is the statement of Corollary 6.1.2:

[image: Corollary 6.1.2]

And here is a corollary to the corollary:

> Assume the continuum hypothesis. Suppose $\mathcal A$ is a model for a countable language $\mathcal L$ and $|A|\le\omega_1$. Then we have $\prod_D\mathcal A\cong\prod_E\mathcal A$ for all nonprincipal ultrafilters $D, E$ over $\omega$.

(3) However, it does *not* follow from Corollary 6.1.2 that $A/\mathfrak m$ and $A/\mathfrak n$ are isomorphic *as extensions of* $\mathbb R$ for all $\mathfrak m,\mathfrak n\in M$. This because in the case of extensions of $\mathbb R$ the language $\mathcal L$ is uncountable.

(4) More precisely the question of knowing if $A/\mathfrak m$ and $A/\mathfrak n$ are isomorphic as extensions of $\mathbb R$ for all $\mathfrak m,\mathfrak n\in M$ is an open problem.

> Are Statements (1), (2), (3) and (4) above true?

Note that, since the fields $A/\mathfrak m$ and $A/\mathfrak n$ have $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ distinct structures of extensions of $\mathbb R$, as [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3763499/660)
by Eric Wofsey, a field isomorphism between these two fields will not be $\mathbb R$-linear in general.

For the sake of completeness let me spell out the condition "$A/\mathfrak m$ and $A/\mathfrak n$ are isomorphic as extensions of $\mathbb R$". Let $\Delta:\mathbb R\to A$ be the diagonal morphism defined by
$$
(\Delta(c))(x)=c\quad(\forall\ x\in\mathbb R),
$$
let $\pi_{\mathfrak m}:A\to A/\mathfrak m$ and $\pi_{\mathfrak n}:A\to A/\mathfrak n$ be the canonical projections, and let $\phi:A/\mathfrak m\to A/\mathfrak n$ be an isomorphism of fields. Then $\phi$ is an isomorphism of extensions of $\mathbb R$ if and only if we have
$$
\phi\circ\pi_{\mathfrak m}\circ\Delta=\pi_{\mathfrak n}\circ\Delta.
$$
**EDIT.** One can easily prove in ZFC that the transcendence degree of $A/\mathfrak m$ over $\mathbb R$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$; in particular it does not depend on $\mathfrak m$. Indeed, for $x\in\mathbb R$ define $f_x\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}=A$ by $f_x(n)=e^{e^{nx}}$ [or $f_x(n)=\exp(\exp(nx))$ if you don't like small letters] and let $g_x$ be the image of $f_x$ in $A/\mathfrak m$. Then a straightforward argument shows that the subset $\{g_x\ |\ x>0\}\subset A/\mathfrak m$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: (1)-(3) seem correct, since the quotient by a maximal ideal in $M$ is the same as a nonprinicipal ultrapower. Why do you think (4) would be true, though?

Comment: @tomasz - My "argument" is not very serious, but here it is: If the answer to (4) was known, I think I would have found it mentioned on the web. (Because it seems to me it is more natural to regard the hyperreal fields as extensions of $\mathbb R$ instead of viewing them as mere fields.)

Comment: There is no problem with regarding extensions of the reals. Indeed, in the usual setting of nonstandard analysis, you extend the reals with *all* the structure (including all constants, functions, subsets etc.). Of course, in this case, a countable ultrapower will not suffice, but in any case, this is routine. I think (4) is probably false, you should be able to omit some type in one extension but not the other, although I have little to no experience with these kinds of arguments, so I won't give you an argument offhand.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3776607/660