# Existence of certain models

Tags: logic, model-theory, filters

Let the terminology and notation of the book **Model Theory** (1990) by Chen-Chung Chang and H. Jerome Keisler be in force.

---

**Question**

> Is there a quintuple $\langle\mathcal L,A,\mathcal I,D,E\rangle$ satisfying Conditions (1), (2), (3) and (4) below?

(1) $\mathcal L$ is a language,

(2) $\langle A,\mathcal I\rangle$ is a model for $\mathcal L$,

(3) $D$ and $E$ are non-principal ultrafilters over $\omega$,

(4) we have
$$
\prod_D\langle A,\mathcal I\rangle\not\cong\prod_E\langle A,\mathcal I\rangle.
$$

---

The article [1] implies that a negative answer to the above question cannot be proved in ZFC.

Corollary 6.1.2 in Chang and Keisler's book implies that, if $\langle\mathcal L,A,\mathcal I,D,E\rangle$ satisfies (1), (2), (3) and (4), then we have $|\mathcal L|>\aleph_0$ or $|A|>2^{\aleph_0}$.

Note that, in the above setting, the models $\prod_D\langle A,\mathcal I\rangle$ and $\prod_E\langle A,\mathcal I\rangle$ have same cardinal, as follows from the Frayne-Morel-Scott Theorem, a proof of which can be found in [this text](http://math.colorado.edu/%7Ekearnes/Teaching/Courses/S20/ultrafilters.pdf) of Keith Kearnes.

Here is a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3765377/660).

[1] Roitman, Judy. "Non-isomorphic hyper-real fields from non-isomorphic ultrapowers." *Mathematische Zeitschrift* 181, no. 1 (1982): 93-96, [link](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01214984.pdf).

Comment: More snappily, you're just asking whether $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that there is a structure with two nonisomorphic ultrapowers over $\omega$, right?

Comment: Also, 6.1.2 in Keisler and Chang, at least  the version I've looked at, assumes CH. Are you assuming that?

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Yes. Sorry for my cumbersome formulation, and thanks for the comment!

Comment: @tomasz - Perhaps I'm making a confusion, but my reasoning is as follows. Keisler and Chang prove a certain statement under CH. Thus the negation of this statement cannot be proved in ZFC. Of course this reasoning assumes implicitly that ZFC is consistent. --- Thanks for your comment and your answer (which I'll try to understand)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Consider the structure $M$ with the universe $\omega$ with predicates for all subsets of $\omega$.

Given any $N\equiv M$ and $a\in N$, the set $\{A\subseteq \omega| N\models a\in A \}$ is an ultrafilter on $\omega$. Given an $N$, denote by $U(N)$ the set of all these ultrafilters.

It is easy to see that for any countable ultrapower $N$ of $M$, the cardinality of $U(N)$ is clearly at most $\lvert N\rvert \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$. It is also clear that $U(N)$ is an isomorphism invariant.

Now, notice that if $\mathcal U$ is any ultrafilter, then $\mathcal U\in U(M^\mathcal U)$, as witnessed by $[n]_{n\in \omega}$. Since there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ ultrafilters on $\omega$, it follows that there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ isomorphism classes of countable ultrapowers of $M$.